# display table row in multiple rows

Tags: html

How to display a table row in multiple rows in HTML? My table has to be responsive.

For example, the table rows are

```
A  B  C  D
A1 B1 C1 D1
```

Output should be

```
 A   B
 C   D
--------------------
 A1  B1
 C1  D1
---------------------
```

Comment: Then may be you can switch to using divs? instead of table.... If your aim is to build a responsive page.. Forget about tables..

Answer (score 0):

Use [bootstrap classes](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid). You can use the CDN if you dont wish to download it.

Comment: hi, my problem is need to display 2 columns and then 2 columns in next , but al four belongs to a single row